# React asynch event handler equivalent of useEffect cancel callback

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, event-handling

If my event handler kicks off an asynch process, how can I know to cancel that process or ignore it's result if the component is rerendered? Like the cancel pattern in Dan Abramov's [A Complete Guide to useEffect](https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/) article.

I did a minimal example :-

```js
const {
  useState
} = React;

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, app);

function App() {
  const [ listitem, setListitem ] = useState("");
  const [ data, setData ] = useState(null);
  
  function buttonClick() {
    retrieve(listitem).then(
      newData => {
        // HOW DO I KNOW IF I SHOULD USE newData HERE???
        setData(newData);
      }
    );
  };
  
  function selectChange(e) {
    setListitem(e.target.value);
  };
  
  return <div>
    <select onClick={selectChange}>
      <option/>
      <option selected={"Spurs"===listitem}>Spurs</option>
      <option selected={"ManU"===listitem}>ManU</option>
      <option selected={"Chelsea"===listitem}>Chelsea</option>
      <option selected={"Albion"===listitem}>Albion</option>
    </select>
    <br/>
    <button onClick={buttonClick} disabled={listitem===""}>Get Data</button>
    <br/>
    {listitem && data && <div>Data for {listitem} [{data.length}]:</div>}
    <ul>
    {data && data.map(function(x) { return <li>{x}</li> })}
    </ul>
  </div>
};

function retrieve(x) {
  return new Promise((resolve) =>
    setTimeout(resolve, x==="Spurs" ? 4000 : 2000, [
      "data1 for " + x, "data2 for " + x, "data3 for " + x
    ]));
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.11.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.11.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

I make that show information for Spurs instead of another team by choosing Spurs, then clicking Get Data, then choosing another team fast, and clicking Get Data fast. Data for the other team shows and then gets replaced by data for Spurs. Like if I pick ManU after I get :-

Data for ManU [3]:

- data1 for Spurs
- data2 for Spurs
- data3 for Spurs

Answer (score 0):

I think I'm not suppose to put this in the question, so I'll put it here.

I thought I could use `useEffect` like in Dan Abramovs article if I had a loading flag. I got it to work but maybe it's not the best way ?

```js
const {
  useState,
  useEffect
} = React;

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, app);

function App() {
  const [ listitem, setListitem ] = useState("");
  const [ data, setData ] = useState(null);
  const [ loading, setLoading ] = useState("");
  
  function buttonClick() {
    setLoading(listitem);
  };

  useEffect(function() {
    if (!loading) return;
    let cancel = false;
    retrieve(loading).then(
      newData => {
        if (cancel) return;
        setData(newData);
      }
    );
    return function() {
      cancel = true;
    };
  }, [loading]);
  
  function selectChange(e) {
    setListitem(e.target.value);
  };
  
  return <div>
    <select onClick={selectChange}>
      <option/>
      <option selected={"Spurs"===listitem}>Spurs</option>
      <option selected={"ManU"===listitem}>ManU</option>
      <option selected={"Chelsea"===listitem}>Chelsea</option>
      <option selected={"Albion"===listitem}>Albion</option>
    </select>
    <br/>
    <button onClick={buttonClick} disabled={listitem===""}>Get Data</button>
    <br/>
    {listitem && data && <div>Data for {listitem} [{data.length}]:</div>}
    <ul>
    {data && data.map(function(x) { return <li>{x}</li> })}
    </ul>
  </div>
};

function retrieve(x) {
  return new Promise((resolve) =>
    setTimeout(resolve, x==="Spurs" ? 4000 : 2000, [
      "data1 for " + x, "data2 for " + x, "data3 for " + x
    ]));
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.11.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.11.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```